# How to disable optgroup from combobox

Tags: cakephp

HI,
I want to remove this optgroup from my cakephp combobox. How can i do this?

Regards,
karn

Answer (score 2):

Well, just don't add it if you don't want it. Basically the select boxes are filled with single array like this:

```
$options = array(1=>'Text 1', 2=>'Text 2', ...);
```

Having optgroup require two dimensional array like:

```
$options = array(
   'Opt Group 1'=>array(
      1=>'Text1',
      2=>'Text2',
      ...
   ),
   'Opt group 2'=>array(
      1=>'Text1',
      2=>'Text2',
      ...
   )
);
```

Most likely in your controller instead of:

```
$this->set('options', $this->YourModel->find('list'));
```

you are using

```
$this->set('options', $this->YourModel->find('all'));
```

Notice the parameter in the find function. Take a look in [that article for Options parameter](http://book.cakephp.org/view/192/options-options)